# Optimized query for a subquery in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I made a query to get the inventory of products as follows:

```
Select 
    b.ProductID, c.ProductName,
    (Select 
         Case 
            When SUM(Qty) IS NULL 
               then 0 
               else SUM(Qty) 
         end 
     from 
         InvoiceDetails 
     where 
         ProductID = b.ProductID) as Sold, 
    (Select 
         Case 
            When SUM(QtyReceive) IS NULL 
               then 0 
               else SUM(QtyReceive) 
         end 
     from 
         PurchaseOrderDetails 
     where 
         ProductID = b.ProductID) as Stocks,
     ((Select 
           Case 
              When SUM(QtyReceive) IS NULL 
                 then 0 
                 else SUM(QtyReceive) 
           end 
       from 
           PurchaseOrderDetails 
       where 
           ProductID = b.ProductID) - 
      (Select 
           Case 
              When SUM(Qty) IS NULL 
                 then 0 
                 else SUM(Qty) 
           end 
       from 
           InvoiceDetails 
       where 
           ProductID = b.ProductID)) as RemainingStock  
from 
    InvoiceDetails a  
Right join 
    PurchaseOrderDetails b on a.ProductID = b.ProductID  
Inner join 
    Products c on b.ProductID = c.ProductID  
Group By 
    b.ProductID, c.ProductName
```

This query returns the data that I want, and it runs fine in my desktop, but when I deploy the application that runs this query on a lower specs laptop, it is really slow and causes the laptop to hang. I need some help on how to optimize the query or maybe change it to make it more efficient... thanks in advance

This are the data of my InvoiceDetails table
[image: This are the data of my InvoiceDetails table]

Data From my PurchaseOrderDetails table
[image: Data From my PurchaseOrderDetails table]

Data from Products table
[image: Data from Products table]

Comment: Right joins... People find LEFT JOIN hard enough to understand, and right join utterly confusing... Do yourself and everybody else a favor and switch to left join, because it's much easier to understand `main table left join optional data` instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Also, doing subqueries within your select statement is notoriously poor for performance. change these to proper joins so that the optimiser can do it's work. Also, if you can post the execution plan on pastetheplan.com and give us a link we should be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: in simple word .. what you are looking for with this query  ? may be you are looking for ..   for each product the toatl sold, stock and remain i stock ??

Comment: where is your DB installed? server or local pc itself?

Comment: i have installed my db on local pc for testing

Comment: yes i wanted to see the total products, how many is sold and the total quantity of products available in stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've taken out your subqueries in the select, I don't think these were necessary at all. I've also moved around your joins and given better aliases to the tables;

```
SELECT 
    b.ProductID, 
    c.ProductName,
    ISNULL(SUM(id.Qty),0) as Sold, 
    ISNULL(SUM(pod.QtyReceive),0) as Stocks,
    ISNULL(SUM(pod.QtyReceive),0) - ISNULL(SUM(id.Qty),0) as RemainingStock  
FROM PurchaseOrderDetails pod
INNER JOIN Products pr 
    ON pr.ProductID = pod.ProductID  
LEFT JOIN InvoiceDetails id 
    ON id.ProductID = pod.ProductID 
GROUP BY
    pod.ProductID, pr.ProductName
```

You were already joining those two tables so you don't need subqueries in the select at all. I've also wrapped the SUM in ISNULL to ensure there are no NULL errors.

I'd suggest using the `SET STATISTICS TIME,IO ON` at the beginning of your code (with an OFF command at the end). Then copy all of the text from your 'messages' tab into statisticsparser.com. Do this for both queries and compare, check the total CPU time and the logical reads, you want these both lower for better performance. I'm betting your logical reads will drop significantly with this new query.

**EDIT**

OK, I've put together a new query based upon your sample data. I've only used the fields that we actually need for this query so that it's simpler for this example.

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE #InvoiceDetails (ProductID int, Qty int)
INSERT INTO #InvoiceDetails (ProductID,Qty)
VALUES (3,50),(1,0),(2,1),(1,12),(2,1),(3,1),(1,1),(2,1),(1,1),(2,1)

CREATE TABLE #PurchaseOrderDetails (ProductID int, Qty int)
INSERT INTO #PurchaseOrderDetails (ProductID, Qty)
VALUES (1,100),(2,20),(4,10),(1,12),(5,12),(4,12),(3,12),(2,20),(3,20),(4,20),(5,20)

CREATE TABLE #Products (ProductID int, ProductName varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #Products (ProductID, ProductName)
VALUES (1,'Sample Product'),(2,'DYE INK CYAN'),(3,'test Product 1'),(4,'test Product 2'),(5,'test Product 3'),(1004,'TESTING PRODUCT')
```

For this, here is the output of your original query

```
ProductID   ProductName     Sold    Stocks  RemainingStock
1           Sample Product  14      112     98
2           DYE INK CYAN    4       40      36
3           test Product 1  51      32      -19
4           test Product 2  0       42      42
5           test Product 3  0       32      32
```

This is the re-written query that I've used. Note, there are no subqueries within the SELECT statement, they're within the joins as they should be. Also see that as we're aggregating in the subqueries we don't need to do this in the outer query too.

```
SELECT 
    pod.ProductID, 
    pr.ProductName,
    ISNULL(id.Qty,0) as Sold, 
    ISNULL(pod.Qty,0) as Stocks,
    ISNULL(pod.Qty,0) - ISNULL(id.Qty,0) as RemainingStock  
FROM #Products pr
INNER JOIN (SELECT ProductID, SUM(Qty) Qty FROM #PurchaseOrderDetails GROUP BY ProductID) pod
    ON pr.ProductID = pod.ProductID  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProductID, SUM(Qty) Qty FROM #InvoiceDetails GROUP BY ProductID) id 
    ON id.ProductID = pr.ProductID
```

And this is the new output

```
ProductID   ProductName     Sold    Stocks  RemainingStock
1           Sample Product  14      112     98
2           DYE INK CYAN    4       40      36
3           test Product 1  51      32      -19
4           test Product 2  0       42      42
5           test Product 3  0       32      32
```

Which matches your original query.

I'd suggest trying this query on your machines and seeing which performs better, try the STATISTICS TIME,IO command I mentioned previously.

Comment: thanks for your response, but i am not able get the right data i want with your query sir.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data so that I can replicate your query?

Comment: InvoiceID InvoiceNo ProductID Rate Qty Gross Discount Net

Comment: no, they're the headers of your data. if you could update your original question with to show those headers but with actual data too we'll be able to work with that.

Comment: sorry i mistakenly paste it, i have edited my question sir with sample image of the data from my tables

Comment: I've edited my answer with the sample data and the outputs that work correctly, take a look and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? (I wrote without testing, as you didn't post sample data nor create table). Please check it and use as a starting point.  Compare results from your query and this and compare execution plan.  **Analysis of performances requires "some" knowledge of Sql and ability to consider several things (eg. how many rows, are there indexes, using of execution plan and statistics, etc.)**

```
SELECT C.PRODUCTID
    ,C.PRODUCTNAME
    ,COALESCE(D.QTY_SOLD,0) AS QTY_SOLD
    ,COALESCE(E.QTY_STOCKS,0) AS QTY_STOCKS
    ,COALESCE(E.QTY_STOCKS,0)-COALESCE(D.QTY_SOLD,0) AS REMAININGSTOCK
FROM PRODUCTS C 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PRODUCTID, SUM(QTY) AS QTY_SOLD
           FROM INVOICEDETAILS
           GROUP BY PRODUCTID
           ) D ON B.PRODUCTID = D.PRODUCTID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PRODUCTID,SUM(QTYRECEIVE) AS QTY_STOCKS
           FROM PURCHASEORDERDETAILS
           GROUP BY PRODUCTID
           ) E ON B.PRODUCTID = E.PRODUCTID
```

Comment: thank you sir your query works but how can i turn nulls to zero?

Comment: @user3819206 I already edited the query moving COALESCE in the upper query.  Is it correct now?  Pls let us know about performances too

Comment: @user3819206  How many records?  Did you give a look at both execution plans (in SSMS)? Did you use SET STATISTICS TIME,IO as Rich Benner suggested?   I appreciate your politeness, but you can omit "sir", if you want :-)

Comment: sorry but im a newbie in sql server so this is quite confusing for me. i have search on net and performed the  SET STATISTICS TIME,IO. i only have 21 records as of the moment i tried running you query and it returned 54 ms for its elapsed time, i also tried my query and it returned 1 ms. i really have no idea which one to look at.

Comment: @user3819206  It's not very important, but you voted an answer who used same query as mine, but he edited after I posted mine...

Comment: sorry i wish i could give you too the vote but i guess i can only give it once,   nonetheless, thank you for helping out i really appreciate it, i just realize that it was my code which made my application slow.

Answer (score 1):

You grouped by  `b.ProductID, c.ProductName` then you could use `aggregate` function to calculate. 
And create `indexes` in your table to improve performance.

```
Select 
   b.ProductID, c.ProductName,
   SUM(isnull(a.Qty,0)) as Sold, 
   SUM(b.QtyReceive) as Stocks,
   SUM(b.QtyReceive) - SUM(isnull(a.Qty,0))  as RemainingStock  
from 
   PurchaseOrderDetails b
   LEFT JOIN     InvoiceDetails a  on a.ProductID = b.ProductID  
   INNER JOIN     Products c on b.ProductID = c.ProductID  
Group By 
   b.ProductID, c.ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your query, I think this could be equivalent (or at least I hope it is):

```
 Select
    b.ProductID
  , c.ProductName
  , Case When SUM(a.Qty) IS NULL then 0 else SUM(a.Qty) end as sold
  , Case When SUM(b.QtyReceive) IS NULL then 0 else SUM(b.QtyReceive) end  as Stock
  , Case When SUM(isnull(a.Qty,0 ) -  isnull(b.QtyReceive,0)) IS NULL 
          then 0 
          else SUM(isnull(a.Qty,0 ) -  isnull(b.QtyReceive,0)) end  as RemainingStock
from  Products c 
left join InvoiceDetails  a on c.ProductID  = a.ProductID
left join PurchaseOrderDetails b on c.ProductID = b.ProductID  
Group By b.ProductID,c.ProductName
```